# z-pass get jagged with depth of field on

Tags: depth-of-field, depth-map

I was rendering meshes and grease pencil with cycles, when I turned on depth of field, the edges of z-pass get jagged. I use 3060 laptop. Is there any way to solve this issue?[image: jagged z-pass]